# How can I use V-mask to display thousands with dot?

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have an input which I want to add a mask to display this kind of format 1.000 or 1.000.000 I mean thousands with dots but the thing is that I have this:

```
<input type="requirement" 
     class="form-control" 
     v-mask="'#.###.###'"
     id="exampleInputEmail1"
     v-model="form.salary" 
     placeholder="Ingresa el salario base del empleado" 
     >
```

It does not work correctly because when I add 1000 it displays 1.000.  with a dot to the end, I wonder how can I fix it? I mean how can I fix that mask? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask) `v-mask` supports `text-mask-addons` - an npm module, which allows you to do exactly what you're asking for.

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" v-mask="currencyMask" v-model="form.salary" />
</template>

<script>
import createNumberMask from "text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        salary: null,
      },
      currencyMask: createNumberMask({
        prefix: "",
        includeThousandsSeparator: true,
        allowNegative: false,
        thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ".",
      }),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/v-mask-demo-forked-t4k3f